# Alamofire Error: Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD33c.png]
I changing Alamofire on AF, not help
Update with pod Alamofire, not help
Add Swift Package Dependencies, use .git

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: AF.request("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&appid=\(apiKey)&units=metric").responseJSON

Comment: Error is - Alamofire request

Comment: That's a different error thatn the one in the question. See the doc, it should be AF.request... https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#using-alamofire

Answer (score 0):

if you are using new `Alamofire 5.xxx` then you will use `AF` instead of `Almofire` it like that.

Just change `Alamofire.request` to `AF.request`.